# Given that 287 = 91 · 3 + 14, we know that any divisor of 91 and 287 must be a divisor of 14

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm reading a book on Discrete Mathematics and there's something I don't understand. It says the following:

> Given that 287 = 91 · 3 + 14, then:
>
> - Any divisor of 91 and 287 must be a divisor of 14
> - Any divisor of 91 and 14 must be a divisor of 287

Why is this true?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|(br+cs)$ for every $r$ and $s$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first because $$\frac{287}{d}-\frac{91}{d}\cdot3=\frac{287}{d}-\frac{91\cdot3}{d}=\frac{287-91\cdot3}{d}=\frac{14}{d}\in\mathbb Z$$ for all this divisor $d$.

The second is the same.

Comment: Why is 287/d−91/d equal to (287-97*3)/d? Wouldn't it be 287/d−91*3/d instead of 287/d-91/d?

Comment: @Arnau It was typo. I fixed. See now.

Comment: I have still one question, though. If you can divide 91*3 by d, does it mean that you divide 91 by d? I'm not sure about that. Imagine you say: 15 is divisible by 5, then (given that 15=5*3) 3 is divisible by 5. It's not true. Am I missing something here? I think I'm not getting the point of this.

Comment: Yes! If $\frac{91}{d}\in\mathbb Z$ then $3\cdot\frac{91}{d}\in\mathbb Z$, which says $\frac{91\cdot3}{d}\in\mathbb Z$. In your example, $5$ is divisible by $5$, which gives $5\cdot3$ is divisible by $5$, which says $15$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: I added something. See now. Also, read please the given again.

Answer (score 0):

$d,r,s,k,l  \in \mathbb{Z}$.

1)Let $d|91$ and $d|287$ then:

$287=rd;$ $91 = sd.$

$14 = 287 - 3×91 = rd -3sd =$

$d( r-3s)$, I.e. $d|14.$

2) Let $d|91$ and $d|14$, then

$91= kd$ ; $ 14= ld$.

$287 =3× 91 +14 = 3kd +ld =$

$ d(3k+l)$, I.e. $d|287.$

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:** If $a|b$ and $a|c$, then $a|(br+cs)$ for every $r$ and $s$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof:* We know that $b=ak$ and $c=al$ for some $k$ and $l$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then:
$$br+cs=akr+als=a\underbrace{(kr+ls)}_{\mathbb{Z}}$$
Therefore, $a|(br+cs)$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

You can apply the above theorem here. We have $a|91$ and $a|287$ (Letting $b=91$ and $c=287$) and note that $287-91\cdot 3=14$, hence let $r=-3$ and $s=1$ which are both integers, hence you know that $a|14$.

The same theorem can be used to show the second statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's better if you make the problem more general.

> Suppose $a=bq+c$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $q$ are integers.
>
> 1. If the integer $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $d$ is a divisor of $c$.
> 2. If the integer $d$ is a divisor of $b$ and $c$, then $d$ is a divisor of $a$.

Your case is $a=287$, $b=91$, $c=14$ and $x=3$.

Proof of 1. Suppose $a=dr$ and $b=ds$. Then $c=a-bq=adr-bdsq=d(ar-bsq)$, hence $d$ is a divisor of $c$.

Proof of 2. Similar (supply it).